# 'No module named' error in Python while importing outside /home directory

Tags: python, import, importerror

Probably this is a silly issue, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm getting `ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree` when I write:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('feed.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

If I run this same script in `/home/` or `/home/<user>/`, it works fine but when my current working directory is `/home/<user>/<some_directory>/<some_subdirectory>`, I get the above mentioned error.

What is happening here?

Additional info: I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and Python 3.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a folder named "xml" or file named "xml.py[c]" on that folder?

Comment: Uhm, very interesting. This very same script was called 'xml.py'. I changed it to xml2.py and now it works. Would you mind to clarify what was happening?

Comment: @Robert `import xml.etree.ElementTree` implies the existence of 3 modules: `xml`, `xml.etree`, and `xml.xtree.ElementTree`. The first place Python normally looks is the working directory, so if `xml.py` is in your working directory, it thinks that's where the `xml` module lives, and then gets confused when it tries to find `xml`'s children.

Comment: Oh, great to know that. Thanks. If you want to copy your comment as an answer, I will be glad to mark it as 'accepted answer'.

Comment: Laurence Gonsalves totally solves my trouble as well! Was naming script as xml.py and run into the very same problem, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try running Python in the place where it works and the place where it doesn't work, and compare the values of `sys.path` when running Python in those two locations.

My first guess would be that you have `$PYTHONSTARTUP` set to something that depends on the working directory.

Comment: The output for sys.path in both location is exactly the same, but maybe this is the problem: The directory in which 'import' doesn't work has spaces in its name (e.g. /path/to/my directory). Any fix for this other than 'Not using spaces in your directory')